# Automation of Open With Dialog under Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, automation

I am trying to write automation code for setting the Windows Internet Explorer as a default browser.
For this, I start C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe and want to handle the popup, the so called "Shell_Flyout" window. In there, I want to find the text "Internet Explorer" and set is as the default program for the file, e.g. .html

This is my attempt so far:

```
static void setProtocolOrFile(string sProtOrFile)
{
    int nTimeoout = 0;
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    AutomationElement aeWnd = null;

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + "\\system32\\openwith.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = sProtOrFile;
    Process.Start(startInfo);

    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_Flyout", "");
        nTimeoout += 250;
    } while (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero && nTimeoout < 30000);

    if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return;

    aeWnd = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);

    if (aeWnd == null) return;

    hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", "");

    if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return;

    aeWnd = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);

    if (aeWnd == null) return;

    aeWnd = aeWnd.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
                            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Internet Explorer"));

    if (aeWnd == null) return;

    try
    {
        InvokePattern pattern = aeWnd.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        pattern.Invoke();
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

    nTimeoout = 0;
    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_Flyout", "");
        nTimeoout += 250;
    } while (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero && nTimeoout < 30000);
}
```

After arriving at

```
aeWnd = aeWnd.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Internet Explorer"));
```

I receive a null reference for aeWnd.
Do you have any clues, how this can be avoided?

I also heard, there is a opportunity to use TreeWalker to find a solution.
What would be your first step or are there any hints you can give me to automatically click this element?